# ExternalEvaluate not working for Python

Tags: python

I tried installing the necessary packages and apparently anaconda already had it. When I ran the FindExternalEvaluator command I got[image]

But when I ran `ExternalEvaluate["Python", "2+2"]`, it said "No Wolfram Language translation found." What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? I suspect that it has to do something with the Missing Dependencies.

Comment: MissingDependencies may be not exact cause of the messages you're getting, but will definitely prevent ExternalEvaluate from working.

You can give a try to this workflow: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html

Comment: It would be helpful to add information such as Mma version, OS version etc. Did you install python using `SystemInstall["Python"]`  from an Mma notebook? When you do this, at least some "missing dependencies" will convert to Automatic or True. This does not guarantee the successful completion of ExternalEvaluate[...]. Please execute these steps and update post if something changes. These days almost every software installs a python directory as a substructure and conflicts make it more difficult than it has to be. Also search prior posts on this forum.

Comment: For the first comment, I already have pyzmq from Anaconda. For the second comment, I tried running the `SystemInstal["Python"]` command but it says "No Wolfram Language translation found." Is this happening because I'm using Wolfram Alpha Notebook edition not Mathematica or is there no difference?

Comment: `Install` ... pls check spelling. In the image provided, which one is the conda installation? ref: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyzmq.  I have not used alpha nb edition, so cannot say. Python 3.8 is not officially supported, although workarounds may be floating around.

Comment: I have installed python 3.9 and under registered it says False when I run the FindExternalEvaluators command. I have pyzmq installed under python 3.9 but it still won't work.

Comment: My understanding is that anything above 3.7 isn't officially supported. Did you install v3.9 as noted above? or separately? or through conda? Mma installs a python version in its own folder structure and will recognize only that. If there were many users of this functionality on this forum, someone else would step forward and help you. I am out of ideas, but if something changes, please let me know.

Comment: This worked for me: `RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python","C:\\...\\python.exe"]`, with your actual python installation path instead of `...`.